# Best way of accumulating values in a map depending on conditional result

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I have an algorithm in Java which evaluates the input variables, if they're not null it does some processing and associates it in a map. e.g.:

```
myMap = new HashMap()

if ( a != null )
   myMap.put( "a", process( a ) )

if ( b != null )
   myMap.put( "b", process( b ) )
```

Considering Clojure usually has no state how do I express the algorithm above in an idiomatic way using it?

One more information is if the variable is null process function should not be evaluated as it would yield a null pointer exception. So something like assoc-not-nil wouldn't do :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when i want to build up a result conditionally like this I tend to turn to the `cond->` (conditional thread first) macro.

```
user> (let [a 4 b nil]
        (cond-> {}
          a (assoc a (* a a 42))
          b (assoc b (* b b 47 b))))
{4 672}
```

This starts with the initial state of an empty map `{}` and then if a is true it uses the result of the expression after a as the value for the next stage, if it's not truthy it passed the value on unchanged to the next stage.

If I'm building the result up from a collection then i reduce it with a function like:

```
user> (let [data [1 2 3 nil 4 5 nil 6]]
        (reduce (fn [result-so-far new-thing]
                  (if new-thing
                    (assoc result-so-far
                           new-thing
                           (* new-thing 42))
                    result-so-far))
                {}
                data))
{1 42, 2 84, 3 126, 4 168, 5 210, 6 252}
```

or perhaps take the simpler approach of filtering out the data that should not contribute to the answer first, then reduce it without worrying.

Comment: A version of the `reduce` that is IMO much nicer is `(into {} (for [new-thing data :when new-thing] [new-thing (* new-thing 42)]))`

Comment: yea, that's more elegant. I like the way into ... for ... when reads.

Comment: I almost never have to use `reduce` to build a map: `into`/`for` is so flexible, you can use it for almost anything, even though it's obviously less powerful than `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info about a and b, one might do the following,

with a,b,c and d being defined as follows:

```
a ;=> 33
b ;=> 44
c ;=> (not set) CompilerException ... Unable to resolve symbol: c in this context ...
d ;=> nil

(->> ['a 'b 'c 'd]
 (filter (comp (complement nil?) resolve)) ; filter unbound symbols ?
 (map #(vector (name %1) (eval %1)))       ; 'a -> ["a" 33] transform
 (filter (comp (complement nil?) second))  ; filter nils
 (map identity))                           ; here identity as dummy-fn for your process-fn
;=> (["a" 33] ["b" 44])
```

This solution only really makes sense if you have named vars (a,b,c,d) flying around in contrast to already operating on some sort of seq.
Also there is probably a much better way